# Sequence $a_n$ is bounded, if $L$ is the set of all limit points of $a_n$, then $\sup L\leq \limsup a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Can I prove it in this way?

Define $A_n=\{ a_n,a_{n+1},...\}$, $~s_n=\sup A_n$, $~\limsup a_n=\lim s_n=s$.

$\forall x\in L$, since $x$ is a limit point of $a_n$, there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}\rightarrow x$.

$$a_{n_k}\leq \sup A_{n_k}=s_{n_k}, ~~\forall k$$

$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} a_{n_k}\leq \lim_{k\to \infty}s_{n_k}$$

$$x\leq s$$

$s$ is an upper bound for set $L$, hence, $\sup L\leq s=\limsup a_n$

Comment: That looks fine. (Your result holds even if $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty$ and $L\neq\varnothing$ and, as an extra result, you might like to show that, if $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ is finite then the inequality becomes an equality.)

Comment: Thank you, yes, it is an equality. The other direction is easy to prove by contradiction, so I only post this part. @jpboucheron